# How to position an image relative of text without moving the text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a h3 header inside a div.  I want to position a small image relative to the h3 header (to the right side of it).  I forgot what is the appropriate way to do that.  With the new code, it is not being positioned relative to the header so if the page is dynamic and content is smaller or larger, the image is not positioned accordingly.  How can I do this also without moving the H3 header?

## original html and css

```
<div class="stages">
  <h3>Stages</h3>
</div>

// CSS
.stages {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
}
```

## new code

```
<div class="stages">
  <div class="graphicon">
  <h3>Stages</h3> <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>


// UPDATED
.stages {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.graphicon {
  width:30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 517px;
  left: 155px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using:

```
position: absolute;
```

You probably want to use:

```
position: relative;
```

There are a lot of resources available for understanding how to position html elements:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="stages">
   <div class="graphicon">
      <h3>Stages</h3> <a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

```
h3{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39j2tbha/

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this with [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```
<h3>
  Stages
  <img src="img.png" />
</h3>
```

In your CSS:

```
h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h3 img {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

Example Here:  https://jsfiddle.net/thec8n0f/

This allows for much easier positioning.  I'm also using `em` here to ensure the sizing is relative to the font size.